# Get image from secured server

Tags: ios, https

I want to use image in my app from a secured server. 
I know how to handle image from simple URL :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
self.image.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

But If I execute this request with **HTTPS server** that requires *username/password* the image won't be displayed. 
How can I handle that ? I heard about **AFNetworking**. But I don't know how to display the image from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using imageWithContentsOfURL in production code, because it will block the main thread until the image is downloading.

Instead you can use AFNetworking 2.0:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
    _imageView.image = responseObject;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
}];
[requestOperation start];
```